# place the data access layer code

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I wanted to know how to place this data access layer code in a class file and call the function in this default.aspx for the protected void submit.I have a stored procedure where i am retrieving the values and passing it here now i want to place DAL in seperate file

Answer (score 2):

make a new `Class` file, for instance

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    //paste your method inside this class, for example:
    public static string returnSomething(string parameter1, string parameter2  /*more parameters here*/)
    {
        return parameter1 + " " + parameter2; 
    }
}
```

You basically have to paste the code you have in your `button_click` event right now, just make sure that you pass all the parameters that you need for the code to work.

when you have this class, you can call the class' method in your button click event:

```
protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{ 
    string result = ServiceClass.returnSomething();
}
```

i made it a static method, so you dont need to instantiate the `ServiceClass` in order to access the  `returnSomething()` method.

Comment: hey thanks Jane it helped me a lot but i am really sorry scom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailComment",textbox.Text);     sorry i forgot to add this to the above code..if i add this in class file its not reading texbox.text..how and where can i add this??

Comment: thats because you need to send it to the method in the classfile. for example: public string something(TextBox.Text). By the way: i dont think TextBox.Text is going to work, since TextBox is the actual object. You need to give your textboxes other names, such as "txtBoxName" or "txtBoxMessage"

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s6p2.html check out that site. I think you need to learn more about the basics before we can actually help you :)